# Cisco forcing Full Virtual-Access Interface due to Framed-Compression response from Freeradius

Tags: freeradius, cisco-ios, pppoe

I'm having a problem with PPPoE authentication on an ASR1001-X where when a session is established it's trying to create a Full Virtual-Access Interface,  not just creating a sub-interface as I want it to:

```
> Session creation failed due to Full Virtual-Access Interfaces not being supported. Check that all applied Virtual-Template and RADIUS features support Virtual-Access sub-interfaces.
```

I'm pretty sure that it's because my radius server (freeradius) is sending back Framed-Compression = VJ TCP/IP.  I'm  not specifying that as an reply attribute though, so looks like it's just set by default.  Log snippit:

```
 *Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  authenticator 53 22 AB ED 7E A5 51 3B - 59 8B 21 0A 16 49 98 8A
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  Framed-Protocol     [7]   6   PPP                       [1]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  User-Name           [1]   7   "CN987"
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  CHAP-Password       [3]   19  *
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Type       [61]  6   Virtual                   [5]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  NAS-Port            [5]   6   0                         
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Id         [87]  14  "0/0/2/1518.2"
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  Vendor, Cisco       [26]  41  
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:   Cisco AVpair       [1]   35  "client-mac-address=000c.42bc.f8e2"
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  Service-Type        [6]   6   Framed                    [2]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS:  NAS-IP-Address      [4]   6   An.IP.Add.Ess           
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS(000015EC): Sending a IPv4 Radius Packet
*Apr 10 15:33:33.837: RADIUS(000015EC): Started 5 sec timeout
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS: Received from id 1645/231 An.IP.Add.Ess:1812, Access-Accept, len 38
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS:  authenticator 37 64 DC EF BA E1 90 D8 - 48 58 C3 78 D9 CD 3E 2A
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS:  Framed-Protocol     [7]   6   PPP                       [1]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS:  Framed-Compression  [13]  6   VJ TCP/IP Header Compressi[1]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS:  Service-Type        [6]   6   Framed                    [2]
*Apr 10 15:33:33.838: RADIUS(000015EC): Received from id 1645/231
*Apr 10 15:33:33.840: VT[Vi3]:Request took 1 msec, 1 msec processing time
*Apr 10 15:33:33.864: %FMANRP_ESS-4-FULLVAI: Session creation failed due to Full Virtual-Access Interfaces not being supported. Check that all applied Virtual-Template and RADIUS features support Virtual-Access sub-interfaces. swidb= 0x7F18F5B493B8, ifnum= 34
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to stop that.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution.  In case anyone else has the same problem, the 'DEFAULT' declarations in /etc/raddb/users define the default Framed-Compression to be sent with responses.  Commenting that out fixes it. `DEFAULT Framed-Protocol == PPP
        Framed-Protocol = PPP
# Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In case anyone else has the same problem, the 'DEFAULT' declarations in /etc/raddb/users define the default Framed-Compression to be sent with responses. Commenting that out fixes it.

```
DEFAULT Framed-Protocol == PPP 
Framed-Protocol = PPP 
#   Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP
```